# OnClickListener is not working for other EditTexts except First-One in multiple edittexts layout

Tags: android

I have 30 x EditTexts and I need to set up an OnClickListener for each one, I have wrote a clickListener and the below code, but the OnClickListener is working for only the first EditText and only once, can someone please point out what is wrong with my code?
Here is my nested for loops to set OnClickListener for all 30 EditTexts referenced by a 6 x 5 array editTexts[][]:

```
public void displaySchedule()
{
    if(!dbHelper.isTableEmpty("schedule"))
    {
        Schedule sch = dbHelper.getSchedule();

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                editTexts[i][j].setText(sch.scheduleArray[i][j].substring(0, 3));
                editTexts[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                editTexts[i][j].setOnClickListener(clickListener);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my clicListener:

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        final String names[] ={"A","B","C","D"};
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScheduleActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_dialog, null);
        alertDialog.setView(convertView);
        alertDialog.setTitle("List");

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,names[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
};
```

And this is the method to set up the editTexts[][] array:

```
public void prepareEditTexts()
{
    editTexts[0][0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_11);
    editTexts[0][1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_12);
    editTexts[0][2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_13);
    editTexts[0][3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_14);
    editTexts[0][4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_15);

    editTexts[1][0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_21);
    editTexts[1][1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_22);
    editTexts[1][2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_23);
    editTexts[1][3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_24);
    editTexts[1][4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_25);

    editTexts[2][0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_31);
    editTexts[2][1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_32);
    editTexts[2][2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_33);
    editTexts[2][3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_34);
    editTexts[2][4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_35);

    editTexts[3][0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_41);
    editTexts[3][1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_42);
    editTexts[3][2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_43);
    editTexts[3][3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_44);
    editTexts[3][4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_45);

    editTexts[4][0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_51);
    editTexts[4][1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_52);
    editTexts[4][2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_53);
    editTexts[4][3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_54);
    editTexts[4][4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_55);

    editTexts[5][0] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_61);
    editTexts[5][1] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_62);
    editTexts[5][2] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_63);
    editTexts[5][3] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_64);
    editTexts[5][4] = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sch_et_65);
}
```

Comment: you need to call displaySchedule() after OnclickListener logic complete.

Comment: just found out that the clickListener is working, but not as I expected, it's work only If I click twice fast, I have no idea why tho

Comment: Instead of making loop to define `setOnClickListener`, use static define to all edittext like `editTexts[3][4].setOnClickListener(clickListener);` will work. Try it.

Comment: for focusable views cannot you just use `View#setOnFocusChangeListener` method?

Answer (score 0):

How did you check your View.OnClickListener?

You should check your View.OnClickListener as the code below to confirm:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.editext1:
            Log.d("Called me", "onClicked " + R.id.editext1);
            break;
        case R.id.editext2:
            Log.d("Called me", "onClicked " + R.id.editext2);
            break;
        ...
        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: My clickListener is displaying a dialog, so there is no need to test it, when I click on the first edittext the first time it works, and when I dismiss the dialog and click again, it won't work, on the other 29 edittexts, the clicklistener isn't working at all

Comment: Hi @Taivna, have you fixed it yet?

Comment: yes, I realized it was actually working, but on double click, 1st click sets the focus on the clicked EditText, and the 2nd click opens the dialog, so I just used  setFocusable(false); on all EditTexts